# Manually align images for time lapse

Tags: photo-editing, timelapse

I've been taking a picture of myself everyday for a few months now. I haven't used a tripod, so the images are not aligned at all. I'm looking for some type of software that will allow me to manually resize, rotate, and crop these images to I line up in all of them. I'm hoping for something where I can have one reference image that is a bit transparent and then I can edit every other image to match that one. Does any software like this exist?

Answer (score 2):

With Gimp there is a script for this: [`ofn-layer-aligner`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). You create two pairs of points, one on the reference layer and one on the target layer, and it rotates/scales/moves the target layer so that the two points marked on it are above the two points on the reference. In your case I would:

- Open the first picture, create the first two points (in the center of the pupils)
- Then for each of the other pictures

  - `File>Open as layers` to add it as a new layer in the current image
  - Add (or move) the two target points over the pupils (you don't even need to see the reference image as long as you don't move the reference points)
  - Call the script
- Crop the image when you are done (this crops all layers to the same size)
- If needed export all layers as individual images (manually but there are also scripts for this), but you can also play it as an animation (`Filters>Animation>Playback`)